# find the position vector

Tags: python, determinants

This is the position vector expression and the question is to plot the graph using Python:

```
r(t) = îsin(2t) + ĵcos(t)
```

And this is what I tried:

```py
import math
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

t = np.linspace(-3, 5, 40)

def P(t):
    t = 2 * i * cos(2 * t) - j * sin(t)
    return t

pl.figure(1)

pl.plot(t, P(t))
```

And that results in the following errors:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-5-a8c79df47296> in <module>

     13 pl.figure(1)
     14 
---> 15 pl.plot(t, P(t))

<ipython-input-5-a8c79df47296> in P(t)
      7 
      8 def P(t):
----> 9         t=2*i*cos(2*t)-j*sin(t)
     10         return t
     11 

NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

How can I define `i` and `j`?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: i add images of errors just now.  thanks !!

Comment: You're missing the point — **don't** upload images of code and errors!

Comment: oops.. i understand.  i just edit now. thanks